# Wpf C# OledbParameters Update where select

Tags: c#, microsoft-access, oledb

Estou tentando alterar uma *query* para usar parameters porém quando executo utilizando *parameter* recebo o erro "Data type mismatch in criteria expression.".
Sem *parameters* funciona normalmente. Seguem as duas *queries*.

```
cmd = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE tblPendencia " +
                         " SET PendenciaValorFator = @pendenciaValorFator" +
                       " WHERE pendenciaId = " +
                             " (SELECT TOP 1 P.pendenciaId " +
                                " FROM tblPendencia P " +
                               " WHERE P.Contrato = @contrato" +
                                 " AND P.PendenciaNivel = @pendenciaNivel" +
                                 " AND P.AberturaData = @aberturaData" +
                                 " AND P.VencimentoData = @vencimentoData)", conn);

cmd.Parameters.Add("@pendenciaValorFator", OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = ((object)item.FatorValor) ?? DBNull.Value;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@contrato", OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = ((object)item.Contrato) ?? DBNull.Value;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@pendenciaNivel", OleDbType.VarChar, 1).Value = ((object)item.PendenciaNivel) ?? DBNull.Value;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@aberturaData", OleDbType.Date).Value = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.DataAbertura) ? (((object)Convert.ToDateTime(item.DataAbertura)) ?? DBNull.Value) : DBNull.Value;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@vencimentoData", OleDbType.Date).Value = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.DataVencimento) ? (((object)Convert.ToDateTime(item.DataVencimento)) ?? DBNull.Value) : DBNull.Value;
```

---

```
cmd = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE tblPendencia " +
                         " SET PendenciaValorFator = '" + item.FatorValor + "'" +
                       " WHERE pendenciaId = " +
                             " (SELECT TOP 1 P.pendenciaId " +
                                " FROM tblPendencia P " +
                               " WHERE P.Contrato = '" + item.Contrato + "'" +
                                 " AND P.PendenciaNivel = '" + item.PendenciaNivel + "'" +
                                 " AND P.AberturaData = " + (String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.DataAbertura.Trim()) ? "null" : "#" + item.DataAbertura + "#") +
                                 " AND P.VencimentoData = " + (String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.DataVencimento.Trim()) ? "null)" : "#" + item.DataVencimento + "#)"), conn);
```

Fiz um teste para verificar se estava retornando corretamente o pendenciaId e somente o select funciona:

```
cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT TOP 1 P.pendenciaId " +
                        " FROM tblPendencia P " +
                       " WHERE P.Contrato = @contrato" +
                         " AND P.PendenciaNivel = @pendenciaNivel" +
                         " AND P.AberturaData = @aberturaData" +
                         " AND P.VencimentoData = @vencimentoData", conn);

cmd.Parameters.Add("@contrato", OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = ((object)item.Contrato) ?? DBNull.Value;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@pendenciaNivel", OleDbType.VarChar, 1).Value = ((object)item.PendenciaNivel) ?? DBNull.Value;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@aberturaData", OleDbType.Date).Value = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.DataAbertura) ? (((object)Convert.ToDateTime(item.DataAbertura)) ?? DBNull.Value) : DBNull.Value;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@vencimentoData", OleDbType.Date).Value = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.DataVencimento) ? (((object)Convert.ToDateTime(item.DataVencimento)) ?? DBNull.Value) : DBNull.Value;
```

Tipos no banco de dados:

- PendenciaValorFator: Texto, 255
- PendenciaId: Numeração automática
- Contrato: Texto, 255 PendenciaNivel: Texto, 1
- AberturaData: Data/Hora
- VencimentoData: Data/Hora

Comment: Apesarde você informar que o select retorna corretamente, qual é o resultado? Algum valor é retornado?

Comment: retorna o id 103092

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acabei fazendo em dois passos:

```
cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT TOP 1 P.pendenciaId " +
                        " FROM tblPendencia P " +
                       " WHERE P.Contrato = @contrato" +
                         " AND P.PendenciaNivel = @pendenciaNivel" +
                         " AND P.AberturaData = @aberturaData" +
                         " AND P.VencimentoData = @vencimentoData", conn);

cmd.Parameters.Add("@contrato", OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = ((object)item.Contrato) ?? DBNull.Value;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@pendenciaNivel", OleDbType.VarChar, 1).Value = ((object)item.PendenciaNivel) ?? DBNull.Value;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@aberturaData", OleDbType.Date).Value = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.DataAbertura) ? (((object)Convert.ToDateTime(item.DataAbertura)) ?? DBNull.Value) : DBNull.Value;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@vencimentoData", OleDbType.Date).Value = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.DataVencimento) ? (((object)Convert.ToDateTime(item.DataVencimento)) ?? DBNull.Value) : DBNull.Value;
```

E:

```
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    cmd = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE tblPendencia " +
                         " SET PendenciaValorFator = @pendenciaValorFator" +
                       " WHERE pendenciaId = @pendenciaId", conn);

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@pendenciaValorFator", OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = ((object)item.FatorValor) ?? DBNull.Value;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@pendenciaId", OleDbType.Integer).Value = ((object)reader[0]) ?? DBNull.Value;


    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```